# Flutter : Fill the image over the body

Tags: flutter, scaffold

I am working on a flutter project. I have loaded an image and I want it to fill up the body. After reading the documentation I came up with this:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home : Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
           child: Text("I am rich"),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      body: Image(
        fit: BoxFit.cover, 
        image: NetworkImage('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQWqFc0Y7fRegMPpHoqNmD-hdba-3Zk_ttQQw&usqp=CAU'),
      ),
    )
  )
);
```

But it does not seem to work. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can directly set `width` and `height` to `window.physicalSize.width` and `window.physicalSize.height` 
And you can use `BoxFit.fill`, see effect below

```
Image(
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
    width: window.physicalSize.width,
    height: window.physicalSize.height,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text("I am rich"),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      body: Image(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        width: window.physicalSize.width,
        height: window.physicalSize.height,
        image: NetworkImage(
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQWqFc0Y7fRegMPpHoqNmD-hdba-3Zk_ttQQw&usqp=CAU'),
      ),
    )));
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thought only boxfit was enough and I was doing it wrong. Thanks for this!

Comment: Hey looks like there is no "window" class. It is not getting recognised in mine

Comment: @shankyyyyyyy, did you import dart:ui, what is your flutter version?

Comment: Omg my bad. Did not import dart.ui. It is working now

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Image.network` instead `Image` widget, as mentioned in [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image). Or, you can add `height` property to image.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = 'Web Images';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
       body: Image(
        height: double.infinity,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: NetworkImage(
          'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQWqFc0Y7fRegMPpHoqNmD-hdba-3Zk_ttQQw&usqp=CAU',
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  MediaQuery for this,it will set the image based on the screensize of phone

```
body: Center(
        child: Image.network(
          'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQWqFc0Y7fRegMPpHoqNmD- hdba-          3Zk_ttQQw&usqp=CAU',
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
```